# How to Customize Grafana

Tags: devops, grafana

I need to customize Grafana.

I have created 2 organization and some users.

I need to create some dashboards that will be visible to only one organization among the newly created organizations.

Comment: What's [tag:devops] in here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in as `admin`
2. Switch to the organization you want. In the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/org/) this organization is called `current organization` and changes will affect only this.

[image]

3. Add `Data Sources`
4. Add `Dashboards`

For other organizations/dashboards, repeat again steps 2-4.